# Lollipop : Mobile data toggle from lock screen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, mobile-data

Mobile data can be switched on and off from lock screen in android 5.0 lollipop. I casually leave my phone on desk for short time while I am nearby, somebody (suppose a kid) can toggle mobile data which can cause problems. For example it can incur a lot of charges if background data is enabled in my settings and somebody switches on the data. Or if I am downloading something in background then it can get interrupted if someone switches off data. Any solutions, tricks, etc. to solve this.

Comment: There are already several tickets open for this: [56644](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56644) since 6/2013 (Kitkat had a similar problem), and [79670](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79670) since 11/2014. Doesn't look like the issue will be addressed. And [according to an XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/to-disable-access-to-quick-settings-t2986003) no way around that except using a custom ROM.